# Better way to convert an int to a boolean

Tags: c#, boolean, int

The input `int` value only consist out of 1 or 0.
I can solve the problem by writing a `if else` statement.

Isn't there a way to cast the `int` into a `boolean`?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

I assume `0` means `false` (which is the case in a lot of programming languages). That means `true` is `not 0` (some languages use `-1` some others use `1`; doesn't hurt to be compatible to either). So assuming by "better" you mean less typing, you can just write:

```
bool boolValue = intValue != 0;
```

Answer (score 192):

```
int i = 0;
bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(i);
```

Comment: this even works if you have a null value. For me DataReader with null values were causing crash, now work like a charm: Convert.ToBoolean(rd["NullableBoolField"])

Answer (score 7):

Joking aside, if you're only expecting your input integer to be a zero or a one, you should really be checking that this is the case.

```
int yourInteger = whatever;
bool yourBool;
switch (yourInteger)
{
    case 0: yourBool = false; break;
    case 1: yourBool = true;  break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Integer value is not valid");
}
```

The out-of-the-box `Convert` won't check this; nor will `yourInteger (==|!=) (0|1)`.

Comment: Not downvoting, but a `switch` case is overkill here.

Comment: Is it really though? As I see it the options are nested ternaries, or an if/else if/else block, neither of those is any simpler or easier to read.
@Marc.2377 - not trying to be awkward, genuinely curious how you'd prefer it done.

Comment: 0 is false, otherwise all integer numbers are true

Comment: @RamilAliyev Not according to the question.

Comment: @Rawling - The question also asks for a "better way" than using an if/else. You focused on input validation. Evelie focused on readability and I focused on less typing. OP didn't specify what they consider "better". Other users can now decide, which of the answers is "better" for them.

Answer (score -3):

I think this is easiest way:

```
int i=0;
bool b=i==1;
```

Comment: This assumes anything else but 1 is false, which like Corak said on their post is the **opposite** way other programming languages use it (ex. javascript).