# How to convert integer to boolean in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, typeconverter

I have stored procedure that returns:

- **0** - no user no app no role in the tables
- **1** - true, there is user, role, app that u require
- **2** - there is no user with that name = false
- **3** - there is no role with that name = false

When I call the Stored Procedure in the C# I get :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'int'

```
public int IsUserInRole(IsUserInRole userInRole)
{
    var model =  _userRepository.CheckIfUserIsInRole(userInRole);
    if (model == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I need to use this to validate the logged User in what role is assign so I can Authorize later based on the `UserRole`.

So I need true or false from the SP, that mean that I need to Convert Integer to Boolean

I have try [Better way to convert an int to a boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108738/better-way-to-convert-an-int-to-a-boolean)
and http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-bool-int but no luck for me there :).

Any advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: You are aready returning `bool`, so what's the problem? Change signature to: `public bool IsUserInRole` and body to(if you want it more concise): `return _userRepository.CheckIfUserIsInRole(userInRole) == 1;`

Comment: You need `public bool IsUserInRole(IsUserInRole userInRole)`

Comment: The stored procedure return byte not bool so i cant make the action returning bool

Comment: @Tozi: but this method should return `bool`, so change the return type from int to bool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will solve your error (having a `bool` return type instead of the `int`) and will make your code shorter:

```
public bool IsUserInRole(IsUserInRole userInRole)
{
    return _userRepository.CheckIfUserIsInRole(userInRole) == 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Let `intVal` be an integer and `boolVal` be a boolean variable then you can do something like this:

```
boolVal = intVal==1;
```

Look into your method, You have specified the return value as `int` and trying to return a boolen value that causing the specified error. If you change the return type to `bool` then your code will works fine as you expected. In more simplified way you can modify the method signature like the following:

```
public bool IsUserInRole(IsUserInRole userInRole)
{
    return _userRepository.CheckIfUserIsInRole(userInRole)==1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i think that solve the problem.I will write back in few min after i test it.

Comment: I have tested the method and it works properly.Thanks