# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Boolean'.'

Tags: c#

When I check output.txt file I see that compiler doesnt show isEnable option which needs to be  `bool`
When I run debuger I see get this message

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Boolean'.'


korisnik.isEnabled = (bool)(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]);
```

I try something but doesnt work at all!

```
 korisnik.isEnabled = (bool)(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString());
```

Whats wrong ?

Comment: did you try Boolean.TryParse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't cast int to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571312/cant-cast-int-to-bool)

Comment: One more duplicate, [Better way to convert an int to a boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108738/better-way-to-convert-an-int-to-a-boolean)

Comment: @AmadeuAntunes TryParse doesnt work at all

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I read this post but can not find properly answer. Doesnt help me at all

Comment: and Convert.ToBoolean(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]) ?

Comment: Thank you. It works ! Please post it as answer that I can vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception says that you are not able to cast the int as boolean. You need to determine on which conditions the int should be false or true.

For example:

- 0 should be false
- every thing else should be true

or

- 1 should be true
- every thing else should be false

---

Here is an example for one of these cases:

```
// when the value is > 0, it should be true.
if(result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0] > 0)
    korisnik.isEnabled = true;
else
    korisnik.isEnabled = false;
```

The `> 0` expression will return a boolean, so you could store it directly into the `isEnabled`

```
korisnik.isEnabled = result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0] > 0;
```

---

If the `result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0]` is stored as an object [*(boxed)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing), you need to cast it first to an int.

```
var userAccountControlValue = (int)result.Properties["userAccountControl"][0];
korisnik.isEnabled = userAccountControlValue  > 0;
```