# getting error in applying bitwise AND in C Sharp

Tags: c#, c++, bit-manipulation

I am trying to translate the below from C++ to C# where v is an unsigned long:

```
(v & 1UL) ? 0x9908B0DFUL : 0x0UL
```

The above had no problem in C++. But when I put the same in C# (v being ulong):

```
(v & Convert.ToUInt64(1UL)) ? 0x9908B0DFUL : 0x0UL
```

I am getting compilation error saying "cannot implicitly convert type 'ulong' to 'bool'.  Can someone advise please?

Comment: Whether it's C++, C, C#, Python, Perl, or any other language: translating a program from one language to another by attempting to find a literal equivalent to each line and each statement, like here: this kind of a simplisitic approach will always end in tears. The correct approach to translating code from one language to another is to perform a complete analysis of each logic unit in the current program, break it down into logically independent chunks, and then implement each logical chunk appropriately, in the other language.

Comment: Yes, in C# the expression of the first operand of the conditional `?:` operator has to be either `bool` or implicitly convertible to `bool`. Your operand is of type `ulong`. So, what do you want the actual condition to be?

Comment: C# and C++ are two very different languages with very different rules for conditions. For example, normal integer values can't be used as implicit boolean values like in C++. Instead you need to [convert it to a boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108738/better-way-to-convert-an-int-to-a-boolean).

Comment: seems there is a function in C# Convert.ToBoolean(...)....

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: In C#: (v & 1) == 1 ? 0x9908B0DF : 0;

Comment: Output will be 0 if v = 0, and output will be 0x9908B0DF if v > 0.

Comment: @kiner_shah: It already is a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @user8677843 `(v & 1UL) ? 0x9908B0DFUL : 0x0UL` -- This translates to this: *if applying a bitwise AND to `v` and `1`, if the result is `1`, then assign `0x9908B0DF`, else, assign 0*. Take that explanation in English, and implement it in C# using C#'s idioms and best practices. What you tried to do is literally take `?` and for some reason you thought you must stick with the `?` syntax in C#, when actually the answer is spelled out in that English description I gave.   Basically it's "what does this code do?", figure that out, and then implement it in whatever language you are translating to.

Answer (score 1):

`(v & Convert.ToUInt64(1UL))` evaluates to a 64-bit unsigned integer. Like John Skeet wrote, C#'s `?:` operator expects a `bool` for the condition rather than a `UInt64`.

Try `(v & 1UL) != 0UL` to the left of the question-mark.

Comment: Right - the source of the problem is that C++ doesn't have a 'pure' boolean - it's 'bool' is  just zero for false and non-zero for true, so conditions can be integer values. You have to study ancient programming history to see why this was every considered a good idea.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas C++ does have a pure boolean type called `bool` (with values `true`/`false`). The first operand of the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) is [contextually converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) to `bool` in C++ (which means that a zero value gets [implicitly converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions) to `false`, and any other value to `true`). And this is not a problem (at least not in C++).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas And the _"source of the problem"_ is that the OP expected different languages to have the same rules, which is not the case, of course.

Comment: @heapunderrun: In *any* situation where you would use a bool, you can use an integer instead. It's not just about the conditional operator.

Comment: @heapunderrun: When bools and integers are used interchangeably, that is a problem. It unnecessarily obfuscates code.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Well, pedantically speaking, not in _any_ situation: for example, try `bool b{42};` (it will fail because list-initialization prohibits narrowing conversions). Regarding code obfuscation, you don't have to rely on implicit conversions, if you prefer to spell those things out (i.e., the C++ standard does not require "obfuscation"). Personally, I prefer the shorter form, and I disagree that it poses a problem. It reduces clutter and increases readability, IMHO. Maybe it's a "problem" for those not familiar with C++, but that's always the case with acting without understanding first.

Comment: @heapunderrun: All programming languages have substantial design flaws. We shouldn't be so zealous that we don't see them in our preferred language.